# is it correct to say it is must for everyone to attend the meeting tomorrow

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to say

> It is must for everyone to attend the meeting tomorrow

Comment: Usually you say "It is mandatory for everyone to attend the meeting tomorrow."  A casual (not very professional) alternative would be to say "Attendance at tomorrow's meeting is a *must*!"

Comment: Since you've requested help on a site devoted to the English language and its usage, you might fare better if you adhered to basic orthographic customs like proper capitalization and spelling words in full.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez If the meeting is *a must*, in my experience it means that it is going to be too much fun to miss. We would talk about a particular football match, or highly rated film, being *a must* to see. *Mandatory* means you have to attend on pain of either getting fired, or incurring the bosses' wrath if you don't. At least that is a distinction which I think would apply in Britain between *a must* and *mandatory*.  I would be interested to know what my fellow compatriots think.

Comment: I agree @WS2.  I wouldn't use "a must" for a business meeting.

Comment: But the OP did not say "a must".  OP used "must" as a modifier, which is clearly nonstandard.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is referred to as *a must* when something is mandatory.  Also you could say,

> Tomorrow's meeting is a "must-attend".

Comment: The important part is the lack of the letter, `A`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. You could say

1. Everyone must attend the meeting tomorrow
2. The meeting tomorrow is required
3. The meeting tomorrow is a must (this is an informal usage; note the article *a* which is required here
4. It is a must for everyone to attend the meeting tomorrow

Comment: I guess you could say _it is a must for everyone to ..._ but it sounds a little clunky.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I'll add that.'

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely wrong.

`Must` is a noun here, not a modal verb.

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/must):

> [usually singular] (informal) something that you must do, see, buy, etc.
>
> *His new novel is a must for all lovers of crime fiction.*
>
> *Trips to Pompeii and Naples are absolute musts.*

You can say:

> It is **a must** for everyone to attend the meeting tomorrow

(You dropped the article in your post).

This would mean that everyone *has* to attend the meeting. Without context, it is not wise to speculate the connotations here. But grammatically, you are fine.